# Stop-Process vs TaskKill

Tags: powershell

I am automating an icon cache refresh, and I am seeing an interesting difference between `TaskKill` and `Stop-Process`. In general I prefer using native PowerShell over DOS command line stuff launched from PowerShell, so I would rather use `Stop-Process -name:explorer` over `Start-Process TaskKill "/f /im explorer.exe" -NoNewWindow` to stop Explorer.exe so that the DB files are no longer "in use" and can be deleted.
However, the former allows Explorer.exe to restart instantly, so the icon DB files I need to delete are still in use and I can't delete them. The latter truly kills Explorer.exe and I have to use Start-Process later. Is there a way to get the TaskKill behavior using Stop-Process, or is this a rare situation where the old school kludge is also the only way that works?

Comment: @christian-müller, thanks for that link. I feel like this isn't a duplicate, in the sense that I don't want to change the configuration of the machine permanently, I just want the process to stay stopped longer. But it suggests that this is a place where the command line hack is the way that works. I can live with that.

Comment: You're using taskkill /force, how about stop-process -force?

Comment: Unless you need to wait, there's no reason to use start-process.

Answer (score 1):

I done some research and you should better end the explorer by sending a message.

With a messaage espacially for this WM_EXITEXPLORER (1460), you can tell the explorer to be closed.

Here my code working for windows 10:

```
$code = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessage", CharSet =  CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern IntPtr PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, uint wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
'@
$myAPI = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name myAPI -PassThru
$myAPI::PostMessage($myAPI::FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", $Null),1460,0,0)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

It better to wait for the explorer windows to be closed, maybe I will add that tomorrow. For now 10 second wait should be enough for the explorer.exe to end graceful.

This is completly better than use the kill at all!

Comment: I am getting an error at line 6 with that, on Windows 10. I haven't tried it in Windows 7 yet.

Comment: Please try again. I made some typo. Please ensure to start a new ISE or Powershell Windows. Or the DLLImport will maybe not work. as expacted

Answer (score 0):

By default, Explorer.exe will restart automatically when stopped by `Stop-Process`. This is handled by a registry DWORD setting `AutoRestartShell` in key `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.

You *can* of course stop that behavior by using

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "AutoRestartShell" -Value 0 -Type DWord
```

If you're on an older PowerShell version that doesn't understand parameter `-Type`, this should work:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon","AutoRestartShell",0,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord)
```

Then in your code, stop explore process, delete the icon DB files and start process explorer again.

Finish up by resetting the registry value to `1`

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name "AutoRestartShell" -Value 1 -Type DWord
```

Comment: the issue here is that, IF my script is terminated before completion, I will leave the machine in a different state from which I found it, with Explorer not auto starting. I would rather not do that, and I was hoping that Stop-Process would allow for behavior like TaskKill has, where a reboot leaves the machine in the same state as previously.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want explorer to stay down long enough for you to delete your files, just add `stop-process` to a while loop. Like so:

```bsh
While (1 -eq 1) {
    stop-process -force -name "explorer"
}
```

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when you're done to stop the loop.

Comment: This seems like a hacky and manual solution. Reading the question, an automated solution is desired