# TaskKill Explorer.exe also kills PS1 launched via Registry Run key?

Tags: powershell, explorer

I am trying to hack together an automated Icon Cache delete, and everything is working fine when I initiate the scripts manually. In PowerShell I use TaskKill to kill Explorer.exe, Sleep for 10 seconds so the icon cache DB files are no longer in use, then delete them and restart Explorer.exe with Start-Process. I am also using a VBScript to launch the PowerShell script as I want this to happen transparently to the user.
The final implementation involves running everything by way of the Run key in the Windows registry. That triggers my script that has a mechanism for running this only once, but for every user who logs on to the machine.
The problem SEEMS to be that killing Explorer.exe also kills the script that was launched via Run, so it never has a chance to write to the registry in Current User that this task has completed. Thus Explorer.exe is restarted on every single logon, which is not desirable.

Is this a known interaction between Explorer.exe and things launched via the Run key? Or might there be something else going on?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to run your script using GPO Startupscript?

Comment: @Theo, no GPO is definitely not a better answer here. Mostly because the script doesn't need to be run for everyone, only those few using Autodesk software, and getting IT in most companies to do ANYTHING takes months, when we need things done in minutes to hours. Doing something that requires real effort, like managing constantly changing group membership, is simply a non starter in the AEC industry. :(

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use the suggestion of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58293257/9898643) and use Stop-Process instead of TaskKill ?

Comment: Does my "WM_EXITEXPLORER" example in last question also kill the children?